# 3D map - data-set visualization on WebGL

Tags: html, webgl

I am looking to make 3D map of my country which will visualize statistical data by region using modern technologies - WebGL / HTML5-CSS3-JS

The end product should probably look like [this](http://plumegraph.org/) or [this](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/) (but for one country only).
I am not very proficient in these technologies, so I am looking for libraries/code snippets which will ease my developing efforts. So far I've got [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).

Any other code or advice I could use with this project? Where would be a good place to start?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth the effort to look into Google's [WebGL Globe](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe)